# YouTube Search - The script runs several times fine and then an error occurs

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, beautifulsoup, youtube

I'm creating a custom search script on YouTube that should display the URL and title of the video, but I'm having problem. For example: it works four times and then I get the error `IndexError: index list out of range`, then the code runs again and after a few more succesful attempts the output shows nothing... 
I know there are many similar questions *(I tried to find an answer)*, but I don't understand why the code works four times, then one times not and why sometimes nothing happens, when the results are always the same?

**The code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

TxtToSearch = "you suffer"
query = urllib.parse.quote(TxtToSearch)
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(url)

query2 = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : "you suffer"})
html2 = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query2)
results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html2.read().decode())


video = []

for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link"}):
    vid = vid.text.replace("\n", "")
    video.append(vid)


for i in range(0, len(video)):
    print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + results[i] + "    =   " + video[i]+"\n")
```

**The first problem output:**

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=you%20suffer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file/", line 28, in <module>
    print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + results[i] + "    =   " + video[i]+"\n")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**The second problem output:**

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=you%20suffer
[Finished in 4.7s]
```

I will be **grateful** for any help. **Thanks** in advance!

Comment: Check the contents of `results` vs. `video`. It sounds like your `results` array sometimes has less entries than your `video` array.

Comment: It seems `results` and `video` come from two different HTTP requests. So you cannot be sure that they are based on the same data.

Comment: I tried it now... The output of `video` is sometimes  `30` and sometimes `0` and the output of `results` is always 62. So, the problem is somewhere in `video`. :/

Comment: Yes but did you check the contents? Also, again, why do you send two different requests and expect the output to have the exact same number of results? And did you check with a proxy like Fiddler what the actual request and response are, or alternatively save the HTML for each request into a file and look at them? It would help you a lot to understand what data is getting processed for each request...

Comment: I mean, `results` always comes from a query to `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=you%20suffer`, so it has always the same results (62). And `video` comes from a different query depending on your input (`TxtToSearch`), so it has different number of results depending on what was searched (`30` or `0` or something else). So obviously they cannot be the same. That's why I don't understand what you are doing there. If they are supposed to both come from the same query, then why do you even send 2 requests in the first place? Why do you need the `html2` from the hardcoded `you suffer`?

Comment: I modified the script and the `video` and `results` run on the same link. However, there is still the problem that sometimes the html script is completely different than it should look like (instead of 800 lines just 400 lines), so `video` and `results` are sometimes both `0`. But I got the idea: in theory, I can loop the whole script and repeat it until `video` and `results` are different than `0`.

Comment: You should check what exactly is in the "bad" HTML and why. Like, save it to a file and open it in a browser and see if you get some error or something else that would indicate what the issue is. Also, I think you don't need 2 requests in the first place, you can do 1 and then do both your parsing on the same `html`. Replace `html2.read().decode()` by `html.decode()` and remove the previous two lines.

Comment: I did as you said and found the cause/ core of the problem in the html file. Sometimes is inside `<body>` only `<script>` ... All `<div>` are missing, so it's probably problem with scraping data...

Comment: Probably that script is a captcha or something like that.